# Nodejs manage different threads

Tags: javascript, node.js, multithreading

I'm a little bit newbie with Nodejs.
I'm working in a Nodejs - express solution.
I want to send and e-mail when some information is added to a MSSSQL database. 
This is working well for me. The problem is that I want to check every five minutes that this information added to the database is modified or not, and if not, send another e-mail.
The call to add information to the db is this route:

```
router.post('/postlinevalidation', function(req, res) {
                //insert function into mssql
                    silkcartCtrl.sendMail(req, res);
});
```

The controller part for sending the e-mail:

```
exports.sendMail  = function(req, res) {

            var emails = "";

            fs.readFile('./config/email.conf', 'utf8', function (err,data) {
              if (err) {
                return logger.error(err);
              }
              emails = data;
            });

            var minutes = 5, the_interval = minutes * 60 * 1000;
            var refreshId = setInterval(function() {
              logger.info("I am doing my 5 minutes check FL_PENDIENTE");

                  var request = new sql.Request(req.dbsqlserver);
                  var sqlpendinglinesvalidation = "SELECT [FK_IDCHECK],[FK_IDPEDIDO],[BK_IDPROVEEDOR],[DE_PROVEEDOR]"+
                  ",[FK_FAMILIA],[BK_FAMILIA],[FK_SUBFAMILIA],[BK_SUBFAMILIA],[FK_ARTICULO]"+
                  ",[BK_ARTICULO],[FL_VALIDAR],[DT_FECHA],[FL_PENDIENTE],[DES_CHECK],[QNT_PROPUESTA],[FECHA]"+
                  "FROM TABLE"+
                  " WHERE [FL_PENDIENTE] = 1";

                  request.query(sqlpendinglinesvalidation, function (err, recordset) {

                    if (recordset.length > 0) {
                      var transporter = nodemailer.createTransport('smtps://user%40gmail.com:pwd@smtp.gmail.com');

                      var mailOptions = {
                          from: '"Mailer" <mail@mail.com>', // sender address
                          to: emails, // list of receivers
                          subject: 'Tienes compras pendientes de validar', // Subject line
                          text: 'Tienes compras pendientes de validar', // plaintext body
                          html: '<b>Tienes compras pendientes de validar.</b>' // html body
                      };

                      // send mail with defined transport object
                      transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, function(error, info){
                          if(error){
                              return logger.error(error);
                          }
                          logger.info('Message sent: ' + info.response);
                      });
                    } else {
                      clearInterval(refreshId);
                      return true;
                    }
                  });
                }, the_interval);
};
```

As I said this is working well. 
I control the five minutes with`setInterval`
But I supossed every time the route `postlinevalidation` is called, a new thread is open, so I will have several `setInterval` processes running.
I want to know how to manage it. If the controller function `exports.sendMail` is running, when the route is called again, "kill this process", and start again  `exports.sendMail`

Thanks in advance

Comment: You 'may'  achieve this by process.exec or process.fork but just go through the doc and you will get it. Node.js is not designed for manual multthteading. If you need to use multiple threads in Node.js so often then its time to switch technology or architecture

Answer (score 2):

> But I supossed every time the route postlinevalidation is called, a
>   new thread is open, so I will have several setInterval processes
>   running.

No, this is not how node.js works.  You don't get multiple threads because of multiple `setInterval()` timers.

node.js by itself is single threaded.  So, each time a route is called, it just creates an event in the node.js event queue and they are served FIFO, one at a time.  At any point that one of the route handlers makes an async call, it essentially "yields" control back and the next item in the event queue gets to run until it yields or finishes.

Timers like `setInterval()` also use the event queue so no additional threads are creates by `setInterval()`.  It is possible that node.js modules that use native code may themselves use threads and node.js uses a small thread pool that it uses for disk managemnet, but neither of those have anything to do with `setInterval()`.

If you explicitly want to create another execution context for a long running operation in node.js to separate it from the single node.js thread, then that is usually done with the child process module that is part of node.js.  You create a new process (which can be a node.js process or some other program running in the process) and you can then communicate with that other process.

> If the controller function exports.sendMail is running, when the route
>   is called again, "kill this process", and start again 
>   exports.sendMail

This is something that would need to be an explicit feature of the nodemailer module in order for you to cancel an operation in process.  How "in process" asynchronous operations are implemented and controlled is not a generic node.js thing, but is specific to how that specific module implements things and keeps track of things.

Looking into the code for the node-mailer and more specifically the smtp-connection module, it looks like it uses plain async node.js socket code.  That means it does not create any new threads or processes on its own.

As for your `setInterval()` calls, you need to make sure that any body of code that creates a `setInterval()` keeps track of the interval timer ID and eventually clears the interval so it stops and you don't keep piling up more and more interval timers.  Another possibility is that you have only one interval and it does checking for all outstanding operations (rather than have a separate interval for each one).

Answer (score 0):

From a quick look, I think you don't really need to put the `sendMail` function inside postlinevalidation. If you want to control it, you could run it in a different script from the express app. You can use something like pm2 or parallelshell to run multiple scripts at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using setInterval then you can use clearInterval to stop the setInterval based on your condition. Whenever you call a setInterval function, it returns an id using which you can stop the setInterval.

```
var interval = setInterval(doStuff, 5000); 
function doStuff() {
  if(your_condition) {
  clearInterval(interval);
  }
}
```